# NodeJS: View and download a PDF from array buffer

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, streaming, arraybuffer

#### My issue:

I already have a solution where I can view a pdf file from an array buffer like so:

```
const data = getArrayBufferFromAPI() // <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
return res.end(data)
```

This opens a PDF in the browser as expected BUT when I click on the 'Download icon' on browser's PDF view [image], it throws me an "**Failed - Network error**".

I already have the code which directly downloads the file as well (without viewing on browser):

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
res.setHeader('Content-Length', data.length)
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=name.Pdf')
return res.end(data)
```

This is not what I want.

#### What I'm looking for:

I am able to open in a browser or download individually without any problems. I need both to work together .ie. open the array buffer in the browser and then click the download icon **on the browser view**, that pdf content should get downloaded.

> I use nunjucks as the view templating engine and I don't use any client side javascript.

Comment: I use similar setup and it always work, how do you handle it in FE?

Comment: @l2ysho - I use nunjucks as the view templating engine. I have no client side javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to specify content-length to do so. When downloading, browser compare content-length and real amount of data recieved, if it not match it is handled like malformed request

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=name.Pdf')
res.setHeader('Content-Length', data.length)
return res.end(data)
```

**Edit**

It is part of HTTP2 spec, look [here](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#malformed)

Comment: i've already tried this ... `'Content-Disposition', 'attachment;` would directly download the file without opening it in the browser which is not what I want.

Comment: How about dynamically set content-disposition header to attachement for download and inline for view? you can make condition by query parameter => `/myfile.pdf?download=true`

Comment: I am able to do them individually without any problems (view and download separately). But what I want is - on click of a single say link, open a pdf and then when I click on the download **of the browser** (the icon shown in the question as an image), it downloads.